Vue: ref does not create a reactive property
TestPage.vue:
<template>

  <div>
    <TestChild :dog = "this.parentDog"  />

    <div v-on:click="this.changeName" id="change-button">
      Change Parent Dog name
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
 import TestChild from "@/test/TestChild";
 export default {
  components: {TestChild },

  methods:  {
    changeName()  {
      this.parentDog.name = "Changed First Name";
      alert("Changed!");
    }
  },

   data() {
     return {
       parentDog: {
         name: "First Dog"
       }
     };
   },
};

</script>

<style>

#change-button  {
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;

  background-color: green;
}

</style>

TestChild.vue:
<template>

  <div>{{this.betterDog.name}}</div>

</template>

<script>
import {ref} from 'vue';

export default {
  name: "TestChild",

  props:  {
    dog: Object
  },

  data() {
    return {
      betterDog: Object
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.betterDog = {};
    this.betterDog.name = ref(this.dog.name);
  }
};
</script>

The output before the green button is clicked:

The data for the TestPage:

The data for the TestChild:

The names of parentDog in TestPage and betterDog in TestChild are the same.
After the green button is clicked, the page output doesn't change. The data changes as follows:
The data for the TestPage:

The data for the TestChild:

So after the button is clicked, the dog prop in the TestChild component reflects the change, but the betterDog data does not, despite using ref.
How do I make betterDog.name reactive as well? Without using watch on dog prop.

refs don't track the variable used to set their initial value.  you're thinking of computed property, or you could accomplish something similar with a watcher.  For your simple use case, you could just use the prop itself in your template (FYI you don't need to use this in template code).  Also, anything returned from data() is reactive.  You don't also need to use ref.  You're mixing Options API and Composition API reactivity, which probably isn't the best idea.

Composition API is supposed to replace options API, it's possible to use them together but this results in poorly understandable and undocumented situations. Here the use of ref is not justified and not useful. data state is already reactive and doesn't need any augmentations in Vue 3. Refs are unwrapped when used inside reactive objects, which is the case here.
A computed or a watcher are necessary to synchronize reactive property with other property. Unless betterDog can change properties independently from parentDog during child component's lifespan, there's no need for it to be a part of component state and no need for a watcher:
computed: {
  betterDogName() {
   return this.dog.name
 }

betterDog: Object is a mistake, data should return initial value, while Object is a function. This doesn't affect how it works here, however.
